# Android app to check webpage for changes

Tags: android, automation, monitoring, productivity

I'm looking for an application for the Android phone to inform me with a notification whenever a particular page changes. It should also allow me to **select the specific part of the page** to track to avoid wrong alarms (the ones I found all did not have that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android app **[Web Alert](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.webalert)** (http://www.webalert.me) is by far the best for automatically checking web pages for changes and receiving notifications. It has several more features:

- View diffs of the changes.
- Free and without ads.
- Stores the versions of the webpage.
- Choose any frequency of the checks you like.
- Automate the navigation process (e.g. repeat the log-in or HTTP authentication)

I have been using it now for two months and it has become part of my daily routine to go through the updates of the websites I am tracking in the morning.